# jQuery : "this" property is not working on $(document) click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change my clicked image src. I tried it using `this`. The reason is I am using `$(document)` for click function. The code I am using is shown below. It will change without using `this` property. But I need to work it using `this` property.

```
$document.on('click', 'img.flagImg', function () {
           _flag();
         })
 var _flag = (function(){
         $(this).attr('src',"images/flag.jpg") 
     })
```

but its not getting. can any one suggest another option for getting a good solution.

Comment: There **has** to be a dupetarget for this...

Comment: Use `event.target` like this `$document.on('click', 'img.flagImg', function (e) {
 var _this = e.target;
           $(_this).attr('src',"images/flag.jpg")
         })`

Comment: @Pugazh: There's a subtle, but important, difference between `this` in an event handler and `e.target`. (`this` corresponds to `e.currentTarget`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a function like that, `_flag()`, `this` is set to the global object (in loose mode) or `undefined` (in strict mode).

Just let jQuery set `this` for you:

```
$document.on('click', 'img.flagImg', _flag);
```

But if you want to avoid jQuery passing it the event argument, you can use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to set `this` explicitly instead:

```
$document.on('click', 'img.flagImg', function() {
    _flag.call(this);
});
```